# Direct3DUWPGame.vsix Template Fails on Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: c++, templates

I am attempting to create a new project with VS 2019 (under Windows 10) using the Direct3DUWPGame.vsix template - which I successfully downloaded from GitHub, and installed for VS 2017 & VS 2019.  However, when I try to create a new project, say "Direct3d Win32 Game DR" using VS 2019, I get the following error message:

```
Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinRT.TemplateWizards,
Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on
this problem and how to enable this template, please see
documentation on Customizing Project Templates.
```

Note that I can successfully create exactly the same project with VS 2017 - so my problem is only with VS 2019.  I should also mention that I have previously installed / uninstalled VS 2013 & VS 2015 on this machine.
In all cases these have been versions of Visual Studio Community.

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a way around it?

Comment: Did you install the version 14.0.0.0 tools in Visual Studio 2019? You'll need to go to the individual packages and select them if not.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by 14.0.0.0 tools.  I have installed the "Desktop development with C++", "Universal Windows Platform development" and "Game development with C++" workloads.  Are there specific components that you have in mind?

Comment: Are you referring to VS 2015 components?  I previously had VS 2015 installed, but uninstalled it when VS 2017 became available.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 installer, Individual Components, Scroll down to where it says build tools (v14.00)

Comment: Thanks - as you suggest I checked the line: "MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)" - but atlas, the problem remains.

Comment: Worth a shot. This probably won't comfort you, but I have a UWP project that compiles and runs great when compiled on one build machine. Another almost identical build machine cannot compile it. The difference between the machines is that VS 2019 is installed on the one that does not work. I'm not using it, but just having it installed broke something. Uninstalled it and no problems. *shrug* Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help nonetheless!  (Meanwhile, I let VS 2017 do its latest update - and now my VS 2017 builds no longer link successfully - par for the course!)